# onShow event fires unnecessarily during each page reloading

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I have an issue with making a menu in my project using Primefaces. Actually, this menu will get me a possibility to show some small dialogs with settings for the workspace (by clicking on menu items). Each dialog should have data lazy loading from database. Unfortunately, when I include my dialogs in the page (single xhtml file or a couple xhtml files with ui:include), an event onShow happens on each page reload and this is wrong and provoke too many unnecessary requests to the database.

Here is an example:

UI part

```html
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:menubar id="mainMenu">
    <p:submenu label="Main menu" icon="ui-icon-document">
        <p:menuitem value="My settings" onclick="mySettingsWv.show()" url="#" />
    </p:submenu>
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="mySettingsDlg" header="My Settings" widgetVar="mySettingsWv" resizable="false"
          closable="true" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" dynamic="true"
          closeOnEscape="true" onShow="#{mybean.onShow()}">
        <h:outputLabel value="Settings dialog" />
</p:dialog>
```

ManagedBean part:

```
@ManagedBean (name = "mybean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
   public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyBean.class);

    public void onShow() {
       log.info("Method onShow is being called on each page reloading, but dialog still has not been shown");
     }
}
```

If I use action "onclick" for `<p:menuitem>` for manual calling the necessary method, it still executes it for each page reloading. Also if I try use actionListener, action attributes it don't work. `<p:ajax>` cannot be attached to `<p:menuitem>`.

What should I do in that case? What is wrong can be in my code?

Comment: You could wrap your dialog inside a div with a 'rendered' atribute so it's not shown on the dom at all until you actually want it to be. and use ajax call to show/hide that. Your issue is that dialog is always shown on the page so the show is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the primefaces [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/dialog.html) for `p:dialog` (same problem with `p:menuitem` and onclick). There the documentation says about `onShow`:

> **Client side** callback to execute when dialog is displayed. (emphasis added)

That means that you can specify a javascript function there, but it does not work that way to specify a action on your backingbean which is called everytime the dialog is shown. What happens in your case is the following: `#{mybean.onShow()}` is evaluated only when the file is parsed (i.e. the `p:dialog` is rendered into the HTML) and then the value which is returned by the method is inserted there (i.e. the empty String).

To fix this you have to define a javascript callback which makes the call on the bean. You can do this by using `p:remoteCommand`:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="onShow" action="#{mybean.onShow}"
      partialSubmit="true" process="@this"/>
```

And then specify this callback as the `onShow` attribute:

```
<p:dialog id="mySettingsDlg" ...
      onShow="onShow()">
```